# Argument 'AdamState' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Searched far and wide, most of the answers were "you forgot to include your controller".

"Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'AdamState' is not a function, got undefined"

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Adam Home</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/AdamState.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
    <div ng-controller="AdamState">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
function AdamState($scope, $http) {
    $scope.test = 1;
}
```

Also, when calling that function from the console it will be called.

Comment: Your way of declaring the controller has been deprecated and removed. `app.controller("AdamState", function($scope, $http) { });`

Comment: Global controller aren't allowed by default anymore. [Declare your controller cleanly](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

Comment: Had no idea it was deprecated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 1.3+ global controller functions are turned off.

So you need to bind your controller to module,

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])

app.controller('AdamState',[`$scope`, `$http`, AdamState])

function AdamState($scope, $http) {
    $scope.test = 1;
}
```

Or you need to declare controller as global controller then do allow global controller function manually form `app.config()` that is in angular config phase, the below code will make your code working.

**CODE**

```
app.config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You miss lots of code there, this should eventually help you get started:

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("AdamStateCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.test = 1;

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Adam Home</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/AdamState.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="AdamStateCtrl">
    {{test}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```